# Best strategy to Update SQLite DB in background task while using Database

Tags: iphone, sqlite, background-process

I have an application that allows users to query an sqlite DB.  When the app starts up it downloads a URL to see if there are any database updates on a background thread.

Unfortunately this causes locks to occur if the user chooses a function that attempts to query the database whilst the update is running.

My question is twofold.

1. What is the best strategy for avoiding conflicts in this scenario.

   - Copy the database to another file update it and copy back
   - Have some sort of singleton operating and use it to schedule operations in a Queue.
   - loop and wait for the lock to open  (although I don't want to hold out the user)
2. Is it possible to suspend the background thread until just before the app terminates and run the updates just prior to application termination.

If anyone has any advice I'd appreciate it as the I am required to run the update without the user needing to stop using the app.

Comment: Still working on it as I've been out on the road lately....

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I believe #1 point 3 is the best solution for your specific problem on the Iphone. Seeing as you're not able to start off another thread to do the background processing, having a small wait (which most programs have in the beginning) is a standard action.

I would NOT try to implement a method where the updates get pushed when the application terminates. Too many times have people stopped (myself included) running an application when they just want to move on to something else.

IMO, waiting at the program start (hopefully not too long) is the best solution to this issue.

Comment: Yeah the wait at the start is not happening as its a background thread the UI is free to use.  Another option would be for me to momentarily lock the user out and tell them that the DB is being updated but I've been asked not to do that

Comment: How long would it take? A few seconds for an icon (hourglass, spinning circle, small animal going in a circle) without a description will never be seen as a forced wait... in today's world everyone is very used to that solution :)

Comment: you could implement an icon, kick off a timer that sends off an event when the background thread is finished.

Comment: Yeah I was considering a UIAlertView / progressView and I already have a fullscreen overlay view that shows a message and a UIActivityView but that might be In use at the very moment the Query or the update begins.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify -it sounds like the database query should be a very short, quick function, though the URL download could perhaps be a much longer operation. Are you holding database locks during the entire URL download operation? If so, I think you want to do the URL download as one operation - and once all the data is received - quickly apply it to your database, thus not holding the database during the URL download.

Comment: The Database queries are short.  The URL download happens in the background again no problem I don't open the DB until the URL download is complete.  The problem occurs when I attempt to process the URL and create SQL statements to update the DB.  The speed of the update isn't necessarily the problem either, just that the user could at the same instance perform a function that requests data from the DB while the update is being processed.

Comment: I guess I'm just trying to understand the best solution given the limitations of the file locking

Comment: Just to me completely clear:  the Update process is happening on a background thread also.